# Regular expression for a range between -5.00 To 10.00

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for .NET application that can accept values between -5.00 To 10.00 (Numeric decimal, up to two decimal places).

Can anybody please help. I went through almost all the examples but none of them seems to fit my case.

Thanks in advance...

Hari

Comment: I don't think a regex is a good idea for this case.

Comment: Regex isn't really designed to do this. It'll be ugly at best.

Comment: Write (or find) a `regex` that matches numeric decimals then, if the string matches the `regex` convert it to float and check the float value against the limits you need.

Comment: Why regex? Why not checking the range with numbers, maybe by converting an input String to a number before?

Comment: .Net is a technology. Which language you are using?

Comment: I have to use regEx. No other option as my validations are done using a xml file which has all the rules defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
/-?[0-4]\.\d{2}|[5-9]\.\d{2}|10\.00|-5\.00/
```

Explanation:

- `-?[0-4]\.\d{2}` matches -4.99 to 4.99
- `[5-9]\.\d{2}` matches 5.00 to 9.99
- `10\.00` matches 10.00
- `-5\.00` matches -5.00

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yL9mF8/2)

Comment: -5 -> 10, not 5 -> 10

Comment: I know how to write a RegEx if I have a range like this -10.00 To 10.00 but here the challenge is I need it from -5.00 To 10.00

Comment: @karthik, ur stuff works. Sorry earlier I tried a few without 2 places of decimal so it was failing. Perfect :)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could do something like:

```
-5\.00|-[1-4]\.[0-9]{2}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}|10\.00
```

But that's really truly uglier than sin.

Be aware, of course, that `-5.00` matches `-5.00`, but `-5.01` *still matches* `5.01`. You might have to add anchors as appropriate.

Comment: Hey, I tried this but fails when u give negative values :(